# Can I add migrations and models to a gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rubygems

I have a gem, not an engine, that I have been building to move my models out of my application. These are just a set of modules that make use of the `ActiveConcern::Support` class/base/module. The table relations are in an `include do ... end` block.

these modules are then included in the core apps models to define the relationships and various concerns.

What I want to do is create a set of migrations in the dummy app, write some spec tests that then test the models and there relations when they make use of these modules.

**Now I have written the migrations I have the models set up in the dummy app, the problem is how to test them now ..**

My question is, should I create the migrations in the `spec/dummy` and the models that use these modules and then use the `spec/` directory to hold all my actual tests?

or will it not work (the way I think it will)? in an engine I would have an app directory and a db directory and all that fun stuff that all the actual migrations and models would sit in, but since this is just a gem I have, like you would in an engine, *just* a dummy app.

So how would I test my new extracted models? is the way I am doing it the proper way? Set up migrations, models in the dummy app, write the tests in the spec app and then do the typical bin/rspec? **will it know to use the dummy app when loading the test database? will it know to use the dummy app for the models it needs to test?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past I've only gone down the dummy app route when I needed to test view helpers, controllers mixing, routing helpers. For what you describe I don't think you need all that.

Firstly for the database side of things, there's no need to use migrations - migrations are for incrementally changing the state of the database. For your usage a schema.rb file is plenty (You could initially just copy the that from the app you are extracting this from)

In your spec_helper you'll want something like

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:adapter => 'sqlite3', ...)
load(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/schema.rb")
```

Obviously you can change how you establish the connection (i.e. from a yaml file, environment variables etc.).

Your specs could look like

```
describe SomeMixin do
  class ThingIncludingMixin < ActiveRecord::Base
    include SomeMixin
    set_table_name :foos #if your table name doesn't match this class name
  end

  #tests go here
end
```

Comment: Could you show an example of how to test relationships between two models? would I just add another class to that describe block?

Comment: Yes - add as many classes as you want. You could also add them in spec/support

Comment: thank you, that was what I suspected but was unsure.

Comment: When your mixin changes the class itself, I found that creating the classes per test is very useful:
let(:klass) { Class.new(ActiveRecord::Base) { include SomeMixin } };
let(:instance) { klass.new }